# How do i get value from combobox, c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm using forms and i get names from database to combobox.
(Table Person(idPerson,name,age))

```
 this.personTableAdapter.Fill(this.test_pmDataSet.Person);
```

How can i get id from person, who i choose in combobox?

Comment: you are loading from table to combobox but you cant get id of object when you choose from combobox. very interesting

Comment: if your answer is answered, please accept one as your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depending on which db you use:

i suppose you have your combobobox populate with the personnames out of your DB

- get the name of the person by:

  string personsname= combobox1.selectedValue;
- Get the id of this person by a query (sql: select idPerson from Persons where name = personsname;)

Answer (score 6):

You probably need the "SelectedValue" property of your combobox control.